# Unresolved overloaded function type when attempting to pass a function as an argument

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I receive the following error when attempting to compile a lone C++ testing file under G++ with C++11 in place.

```
spike/cur_spike.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
spike/cur_spike.cpp:60:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘callFunctionFromName(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::__cxx11::string&)’
     callFunctionFromName (outputLine, param);
                                            ^
spike/cur_spike.cpp:49:7: note: candidate: template<class funcT, class ... Args> funcT callFunctionFromName(funcT (*)(Args ...), Args ...)
 funcT callFunctionFromName (funcT func(Args...), Args... args) {
       ^
spike/cur_spike.cpp:49:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
spike/cur_spike.cpp:60:44: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘funcT’
     callFunctionFromName (outputLine, param);
                                            ^
```

Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


template <typename T>
void outputLine (T text) {
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
}

template <typename funcT>
funcT callFunctionFromName (funcT func()) {
    return func ();
}
template <typename funcT, typename... Args>
funcT callFunctionFromName (funcT func(Args...), Args... args) {
    return func (args...);
}

int main () {  
    std::string param = "Testing...";
    callFunctionFromName (outputLine, param);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm currently building this on a Linux system using G++, this code snippet contains all code related to this issue. I'm particularly intrigued about the fact that the compiler is unable to deduce the template parameter `funcT` for some reason, even though the `outputLine` function has a clear return type of void.

Setting a pointer of `outputLine` using `void (*outputLinePtr)(std::string) = outputLine` and using the pointer as the argument instead does nothing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually set template argument.

```
callFunctionFromName (outputLine<std::string>, param);
```

Comment: Well, uh, that worked. I have no idea why though. May you give me a link or some reference I can read concerning this `<>` syntax? I'm new to C++ so sorry for the seemingly ignorant question. Thank you!

Comment: @Wintro it's just explicit instantiation of function. You tell compiler, that you want use `outputLine` for type `std::string`.

Comment: Aha, alright thank you. Is there no way though to make it stay generic, i.e. if I wanted to pass in a value to `outputLine` through the `callFunctionFromName` that I did not know it's type until the moment of passing?

Comment: @Wintro compiler doesn't know what function is outputLine, it's just `<unresolved overloaded function type>`. Why you cannot manually specify function type in call site?

Comment: Oh, so the compiler cannot figure out what the function is exactly unless I specify which overload I want? I get it now. Thank you. I can specify the type, but I was asking just as a general question.

Comment: @Wintro not exactly. Compiler cannot choose what the function you want, if it's template function (or overloaded function) and you send this function to another template function.